# Byte > Char > String > Encode > Whut

Tags: c#, encoding, .net-3.5

So i was QC'n some code from a colleague and stumbled over this piece of code.

```
Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("" + (char)0x1b + (char)0x40));
```

So were transmitting binary to an LPT printer. I asked my colleague what the hell is going on. Why is he converting from byte[] to byte[] with so many steps in between, i figured an array literal would suffice. My colleague argued that the encoding of the compiler might be different. He was uncertain he added. So am I because this is copied from an old codebase where there might have been a reason. Are all these step really necessary?

Comment: "The encoding of the compiler" doesn't make much sense to me.  The encoding is specified right there in the code.  It can only be ascii, which is pretty well specified.  It's not machine-dependent.  I can't see how this code would ever have different behavior than using the array directly.

Comment: I would use this : Write( new byte[] {0x1b,0x40});

Comment: I've though the same. Thanks. This is an answer. I thought there was an idea behind it because it's repeated numerous times throughout a 7 year old codebase. But i can't think of any way this would result in anything other than 2 bytes. Unless the encoding of the system is different. I know string literals are encoded the same way as the document is. Which happens to be in Chinese.

Comment: By the way. I think the C# compiler is clever enough to concatenate the strings compile time. So the whole expression inside GetBytes(XX) should become a single string constant after compilation?